# Adobe Acrobat separate print and view orientation

Tags: pdf, printing, adobe, orientation, acrobat

I have a PDF with multiple pages in landscape orientation. I want them to be printed in portrait orientation without using the auto rotate function in the print dialog. (this function isn't available in the software which handles the actual printing (a custom .Net application). Is there a way to define different view and print orientation?